# Where did drush language-add disappear?

Tags: drush, i18n-l10n

I was using it for a long time in the install script and today it stopped working and I don't remember changing anything related.

> The drush command 'language-add' could not be found.

Was it part of `l10n_update` (I have it enabled), drush itself or something else?

This https://drupal.org/project/drush_language is not what I'm looking for. It doesn't work and I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by not installing *drush_language* in the correct directory.
If you stil have the problem:

First remove anything related to drush_language:

1. Go to your drupal folder and do `drush pmu drush_language`
2. Go to `/drupal/sites/all/modules` and delete the directory `drush_language`, if it's there.
3. check your system for a global `drush_language`: e.g. do `updatedb` & `locate drush_language`. Then delete any folders called `drush_language`.
4. Go back to your drupal root folder an do: `drush dl drush_language --destination=./sites/all/modules/`

Comment: drush_language should be in the folder like "~/.drush/drush_language"